# Recognize Variable Globally in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, variables

How to Recognize Variable Globally in VB.NET? I have the code below, my problem is that VB.NET does not recognize the variables "Z_lenght" and "Z_width" outside the IF Statement (i.e. after ENDIF).

```
    Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        If TextBox1.Text > TextBox2.Text Then
            Dim Z_lenght = TextBox1.Text
            Dim Z_width = TextBox2.Text
        Else
            Dim Z_lenght = TextBox2.Text
            Dim Z_width = TextBox1.Text
        End If

        Dim Z_area = Z_lenght * Z_width
        RichTextBox1.AppendText("Length = " & Z_lenght)
        RichTextBox1.AppendText("Width = " & Z_width)
        RichTextBox1.AppendText("Area = " & Z_area)
    End Sub

End Class
```

I appreciate any help/comment.

Comment: Declaring them in the if statement means they will only be in scope in the if statement. You can declare them as a class level variable for visibility in the entire class. Or create a module and make the variables public for visibility in the application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim Z_length As Double = 0
    Dim Z_width As Double = 0
    Dim Z_area As Double = 0
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        If TextBox1.Text > TextBox2.Text Then
            ' I don't know what you're trying to achieve here, 
            ' but I recommend try using Double.TryParse()
            Double.TryParse(TextBox1.Text, Z_length)
            Double.TryParse(TextBox2.Text, Z_width)
        Else
            Double.TryParse(TextBox2.Text, Z_length)
            Double.TryParse(TextBox1.Text, Z_width)
        End If

        Z_area = Z_length * Z_width
        RichTextBox1.AppendText("Length = " & Z_length)
        RichTextBox1.AppendText("Width = " & Z_width)
        RichTextBox1.AppendText("Area = " & Z_area)
    End Sub

End Class
```

This will make `Z_Length`, `Z_width` and `Z_area` usable in class `Form1`

Comment: Much appreciated Codemunkeee; I accepted the answer. This forum is for both advanced and beginners and all using it through search engines to get answers. Someone who do not know the answer ranked the question (-1) instead of being positive and post the answer. I really appreciate your answer and help.

Comment: and (+1) for your answer Codemunkeee. Hope other beginners will find it useful.

Answer (score 0):

declare your variables outside of the if else scope.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t0wsc67.aspx

> If you declare a variable within a block, you can use it only within
>   that block. In the following example, the scope of the integer
>   variable cube is the block between If and End If, and you can no
>   longer refer to cube when execution passes out of the block.

Given your comments, it seems you should review variable scopes.  You can use your variables outside your if-else inside your if-else.

Comment: Hi DeveloperGuro; you missed the example, can you please post.

Comment: I know we can declare the variable if the value is fixed outside that block; but how to declare it if its value is dependant on other variables inside the block as per my example above?

Comment: It is ironic, someone who did not answer the question gave (-1) to the question. It is better to be positive and answer the question IF you know the answer, I am beginner and that is why I am here asking this simple question.